# How to fix missing values in interpolation using interp2xyz in AKIMA

Tags: r, ggplot2, interpolation, contour

I'm trying to interpolate my irregularly spaced set of points at the following coordinates which represent PM concentrations and then produce a contour map which represents PM concentration throughout the area. I used interp2xyz of AKIMA to interpolate but notice those little triangular white spots on the contour map. Are they missing values from not being able to extrapolate using mean values? How do I fix those to produce smooth contour map?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(akima)

site <- c(1:20)

long <- c(171.2496,171.1985,171.2010, 171.2076, 171.2236,171.2165,171.2473,171.2448,171.2416,171.2243,171.2282,171.2344,171.2153,171.2532,171.2444,171.2443,171.2562,171.2330,171.2356,171.2243)

lati <- c(-44.40450,-44.38520,-44.38010,-44.38530,-44.38750,-44.39195,-44.41436,-44.38798,-44.38934,-44.37958,-44.37836,-44.37336,-44.37909,-44.40801, -44.40472,-44.39558,-44.39919,-44.40971,-44.39577,-44.39780)

PM <- c(57,26,12,39,44,48,31,44,46,33,29,12,29,51,50,43,28,40,45,33)

fixed <- cbind(site,long,lati,PM)

### interpolate from fixed monitors

interpdf <-interp2xyz(interp(x=fixed$long, y=fixed$lati, z=fixed$PM, duplicate="mean"), data.frame=TRUE) %>%
  filter(!is.na(z)) %>%
  tbl_df() 


ggplot(interpdf, aes(x=x,y=y,z=z, fill=z)) + 
  geom_contour(binwidth = 0.0005, aes(color= ..level..)) + 
  scale_color_distiller("PM", palette = "Spectral", limits = c(0, 70)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: PMcontour_map]

Comment: For surfaces, I recommend using the plot method for rasters. This works nicely -> `plot(raster::rasterFromXYZ(interpdf))` <- You may need to install the `raster` library first.

Comment: In other words, those white spots are plotting artifacts from ggplot2, I'm pretty sure. The akima interpolation is probably working fine.

Comment: I'm getting an error from the attempt at creation of interpdf: "Error in is.list(al) : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". Not surprising since $ is illegal when dealing with matrices.

Comment: Thanks @JMT2080AD I tried using your code with raster and it works but the map is not smooth as using geom_contour & ggplot2. Is there another way to have a smoother surface map (ie. not jagged)?

Answer (score 1):

`akima::interp` is creating a grid from irregular points by interpolating values for unknown locations from known locations. This function puts the results on a grid that the user can define. In your example you do not define a grid so, as the function help indicates:

> The default is 40 points evenly spaced over the range of x.

You would like a smooth grid. This is done a number of ways. Interpolate higher resolution values on the screen or in the data.

Hijmans describes a few methods here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152533/19056

Or you can also increase the resolution parameters of the `interp` function.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks so much @JMT2080AD for your help here. This is awesome!

Comment: I also try ggplot with geom_raster and it gives similar graph to using plot(raster::rasterFromXYZ(interpdf))

Comment: ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = interpdf , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_distiller("PM", palette="Spectral", na.value="white",limits = c(0, 70)) + 
  theme_bw()